# How to update an array in react using prevState?

Tags: reactjs

How to update an array in react using prevState?

I want to insert a record into the array.

I found an information that should not be used to push for state preservation measure.

```
this.state = {
            dados : {
                doc: '',
                infe: '',
                bene: '',
                inco: [],
                cino: [],
            }
        }

this.setState(prevState => ({ dados:{
                inco: [...prevState.dados.inco, URL.createObjectURL(result)]
            }}))

this.setState(prevState => ({ dados:{
                cino: [...prevState.dados.cino, URL.createObjectURL(result)]
            }}))
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Is result variable appropriate? Plus i think your dados state variable is getting overwritten in first setstate function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to **club the setstate() function call into one**, as dados state key might lose other properties, hence it cannot find cino object in second setstate(). **Here dados state object was getting only inco property after first setState() function cal**l, hence now below code we are making sure consistency in state object is maintained

Here is sample code

```
 this.state = {
            dados : {
                doc: '',
                infe: '',
                bene: '',
                inco: [],
                cino: [],
            }
        }

this.setState(prevState => (
                 { 
                    dados:{
                            ...prevState.dados,
                            inco: [...prevState.dados.inco,
                                    URL.createObjectURL(result)
                                  ],
                            cino: [...prevState.dados.cino,
                                    URL.createObjectURL(result)
                                  ]
            }}))
```

Comment: Its Work. Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var exp = Object.assign([],data.questions);

   exp[index] = {
                 name:name,
                 question:question,
                 [event.target.name]:event.target.value
  }
   setData({
              ...data,
              questions:exp
   })
```